# Wildfly 8.2.1 final throw AN EXCEPTION JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I have a question on `wildfly server`. You can see this error in the top image link. I think this problem happens because of `JVM` but I couldn't fix it.

My OS is `windows7` and I had installed `jdk 1.7 and 1.8.`

I changed default `jdk` to 1.7 . But I have also tried with `jdk 1.8` and it was not working.

> 17:54:47,273 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version
>   1.3.3.Final 17:54:47,761 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final 17:54:47,858 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service
>   thread 1-8) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" starting
>   17:54:48,358 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot:
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException:
>   JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:112)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:259)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21] Caused by:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: JBAS014674: Failed to load module
>   org.jboss.as.configadmin  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:155)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:325)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:137)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:107)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:104)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  ... 3 more Caused
>   by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: JBAS014674: Failed to load module
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:147)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  ... 9 more Caused
>   by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: JBAS014674: Failed to load
>   module    at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:196)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.access$000(ExtensionXml.java:69)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:127)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:124)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]     at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
>   [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final] Caused by:
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.as.configadmin:main     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:240)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:178)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  ... 9 more
>
> 17:54:48,368 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner;
>   exiting. See previous messages for details. 17:54:48,412 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015950: WildFly
>   8.2.1.Final "Tweek" stopped in 34ms

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have copied a `standalone.xml` file from a JBossAS 7.x (or possibly WildFly 8.0) installation into your WildFly 8.2 installation.

The module `org.jboss.as.configadmin:main` existed in these earlier versions but not later.

These configuration files are not generally forward or backwardly compatible between versions.